# Nginx regex issue for domain name filter

Tags: regex, nginx, webserver

My website has different themes for mobile and desktop pages and that's why I want to filter the homepage as the cache is breaking the UI on devices. I tried adding:

```
# Don't cache domain names 
if ($request_uri ~* "sciencehook.com($|/$)") { 
set $skip_cache 1; 
}
```

but it didn't work. It's caching sciencehook.com anyways. Please let me know the mistake here.

Cache section looks like this:

```
# Don't cache domain names 
if ($request_uri ~* "sciencehook.com($|/$)") { 
set $skip_cache 1; 
} 

# Don't cache uris containing the following segments 
if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") { 
set $skip_cache 1; 
} 

# Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters 
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") { 
set $skip_cache 1; 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: is this regex correct without forward slashes? `($|/$)`  you dont have to do `/sciencehook.com($|/$)/` ?

Comment: `$request_uri` does not contain the host name. You will need to look at `$host` or `$http_host` or create a separate `server` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith just removed sciencehook.com and it's working now. Thanks for replying.